# Ellipse is the locus of points for which the distance from a point is proportional to the distance from the directrix

Tags: conic-sections

Can  anyone please tell me how to prove this ellipse is the locus of points for which the distance from a point (focus) is proportional to the distance from the directrix from the following picture ?

[image]

Comment: See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/137462/255730

Comment: @sani Also see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047706/reconciliation-of-cone-slicing-and-focus-directrix-definitions-of-conic-sections/2058073#2058073

Comment: Thank you for sharing the links